# Add a mathematical operation to standard TCL ones

Tags: runtime, tcl

As you know TCL has some mathematical functions such as **sin**, **cos**, and **hypot** that are called in **expr** command with **()** braces as follows:

```
puts [expr sin(1.57)]
```

Now how can I add a function using TCL [library functions](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclLib/contents.htm) so that it was called exactly the same way, and was doing something that a certain **proc** defines.

I would like to clarify my question. Say there is a proc (string) as follows:

```
proc add { a b } { return [expr $a+$b] } ;# string of a proc
```

Also I have a TCL interpreter in my C++ code. Now I want get the *string of a proc* and runtime register a function called **add** into the [tcl::mathfunc namespace](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclLib/CrtMathFnc.htm) (I guess I should use [Tcl_CreateObjCommand](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclLib/CrtObjCmd.htm)) so that I could call the following:

```
puts [expr add(1.57, 1.43)]
```

How this can be done. Could you please write a simple example. I could not find any example in TCL documentation and in books as well which describe the usage of [this command](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclLib/CrtObjCmd.htm).

Comment: Technically, it's not a command. It's a function in Tcl's C API…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creating a function from C isn't too hard. To do it, you've got to write an implementation of a command that will perform the operation, and register that implementation as a command in the correct namespace. (In 8.4 and before, functions were done with a separate interface that was quite a bit nastier to use; the mechanism was wholly overhauled in 8.5.)

### Command Implementation

Note that the signature is defined, and the `ignored` parameter is not used here. (It's really a `void *` — *great* when you're wanting to do things like binding a command to an object — but it simply isn't needed for doing an addition.)

```c
static int AddCmd(ClientData ignored, Tcl_Interp *interp, int objc,
        Tcl_Obj *const objv[]) {
    double x, y, sum;

    /* First, check number of arguments: command name is objv[0] always */
    if (objc != 3) {
        Tcl_WrongNumArgs(interp, 1, objv, "x y");
        return TCL_ERROR;
    }

    /* Get our arguments as doubles */
    if (    Tcl_GetDoubleFromObj(interp, objv[1], &x) != TCL_OK ||
            Tcl_GetDoubleFromObj(interp, objv[2], &y) != TCL_OK) {
        return TCL_ERROR;
    }

    /* Do the real operation */
    sum = x + y;

    /* Pass the result out */
    Tcl_SetObjResult(interp, Tcl_NewDoubleObj(sum));
    return TCL_OK;
}
```

Don't worry about the fact that it's allocating a value here; Tcl's got a very high performance custom memory manager that makes that a cheap operation.

### Command Registration

This is done usually inside an initialization function that is registered as part of a Tcl package definition *or* which is called as part of initialization of the overall application. You can also do it directly if you are calling `Tcl_CreateInterp` manually. Which you do depends on how exactly how you are integrating with Tcl, and that's quite a large topic of its own. So I'll show how to create an initialization function; that's usually a good start in all scenarios.

```c
int Add_Init(Tcl_Interp *interp) {
    /* Use the fully-qualified name */
    Tcl_CreateObjCommand(interp, "::tcl::mathfunc::add", AddCmd, NULL, NULL);
    return TCL_OK;
}
```

The first `NULL` is the value that gets passed through as the first (`ClientData`) parameter to the implementation. The second is a callback to dispose of the `ClientData` (or NULL if it needs no action, as here).

Doing all this from C++ is also quite practical, but remember that Tcl is a *C* library, so they have to be functions (not methods, not without an adapter) and they need C linkage.

---

To get the body of a procedure from C (or C++), by far the easiest mechanism is to use `Tcl_Eval` to run a simple script to run `info body theCmdName`. Procedure implementations are *very complex indeed*, so the interface to them is purely at the script level (unless you actually entangle yourself far more with Tcl than is really wise).

Comment: And really, if you were *really* doing `add` I'd tell you to use the command `::tcl::mathop::+` as Tcl is able to do more advanced optimizations with it.

Comment: This is not exactly what I want, but thanks for long writing for me. It helped me as an example how I can use these function. Thank you very much! :)

Comment: but seams these is a problem with registration. Tcl_CreateObjCommand(interp, "::tcl::mathfunc::add", AddCmd, NULL, NULL); command does not work. But when I try with Tcl_CreateMathFunc command a math function is being registered. Is there a mistake?

Comment: **Seems it is the version of TCL**. I have now TCL 8.4 but seams the trick with ::tcl::mathfunc namespace works for 8.5 and later.